# How to bind data to query repeater in Kentico CMS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I try to connect query repeater in kentico to data source (in this case it is custom table), unfortunately I have to do it in .aspx and code behind, not in webpart properties as always. 
I know that in CMS repeater I can do it in this way:

> ```
> <cms:CMSRepeater ID="CMSRepeater1" runat="server" 
>         Path="/%"
>         ClassNames="CustomTable.MyTable"
>         EnablePaging="False"             
>         StopProcessing="false"
>         SelectOnlyPublished="true"
>         >
>         <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
>         <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Description") %></ItemTemplate>    
>         <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
> </cms:CMSRepeater>
> ```

Unfortunately it is custom table so this construction doesn't work, I should use queryrepeater, nut how can I bind data in this control?

> ```
> <cms:queryrepeater id="repItems" runat="server"  > 
>  <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
>  <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Description") %></ItemTemplate>    
>  <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate> 
> </cms:queryrepeater>
> ```

I don't have a path, I tried also datasource="CustomTables.MyTable" but it also doesn't work... Help ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We were discussing this here - [Kentico forums](http://devnet.kentico.com/Forums.aspx?forumid=67&threadid=41731) where I explained how to use data source web part/control together with repeater control - you need to use two controls.